# How to flip page transition like ibook in react native

Tags: react-native

Iam new to react native, I used turn.js package to implement flip book but it doesn't work, Please help

Comment: use this https://github.com/darenju/react-flip-page

Comment: show some code - be more clear with the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Iam used react native and i don't know to implement react.js packages in react native. I found that turn.js package which perform exactly like ibook.